# Framework to build API REST service for Redis database?

Tags: rest, api, service, redis, server

We start buliding an application like Tinder but not exactly the same :) We want to make a Rest service with API for Redis database to get the best performance for multiple queries going from client app. Which framework we can use? Which can offer the best performace with lowest latency?
Programming language is irrelevant for us. We will be appriciated if someone can give us advice. We must use the best technology.

Best regards for all of You :)

Comment: multiple queries means the redis db can handle that very easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. Better go with the Oracle database compared to the Redis database,
   because in future it will become an problem for your code
2. Redis with your source code will be always tightly coupled very much
   compared to other databases.also in redis they are not providing much
   support for the customers as compared to the oracle database.

   The information availability for the redis database is very lower and
   oracle is pretty higher and convenient and easy to use it.
3. The one best thing it will give best performance from db compared to
   other db .redis db much more milliseconds faster response time.

   but anyway i will provide some link that will help you.

[Redis DB Documentaion](https://redis.io/documentation)

[Redis DB Discussions in Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/redis-dev)